# Unmarshaller throws IllegalAccessError on simple XML String parsing

Tags: java, xml, open-liberty

I would like to deserialize a simple xml string to an object using the **javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller** in an java EE application running in open-liberty. I have following method to deserialize:

### Deserialize

```
package com.my.deserializer;

public class XmlDeserializer {
    private static Name deserialize() {
        try {
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Name.class);
            Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();           

            StringReader reader = new StringReader("<Name xml:lang=\"en\">Acme, Inc.</Name>");
            Name cXml = (Name) unmarshaller.unmarshal(reader);
            return cXml;
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

### Class

```
package com.my.model;

@XmlRootElement(name = "Name")
public class Name implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4018453444627994825L;

    @XmlAttribute(name = "lang", namespace = "xml")
    public String lang;
    
    @XmlValue
    public String text;
}
```

When I call `XmlDeserializer.deserialize()`, I get following exception:

`java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access class com.my.model.Name from class com.my.deserializer.XmlDeserializer`

I only can get this code working if I change class name from `Name` to any other name e.x. `Name_Entity`. Is there anything wrong with my code?

### System specs

- Windows 10 x64
- Eclipse 2020-06
- Java SE-1.8
- Maven Dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

OpenLiberty (v. 20.0.0.9)

Feautures:

```
<feature>webProfile-8.0</feature>
<feature>mpJwt-1.1</feature>
<feature>localConnector-1.0</feature>
<feature>mpHealth-2.2</feature>
<feature>jaxws-2.2</feature>
```

Comment: What features do you have enabled?  And what version of Open Liberty are you running?  Not sure it matters, but how are you getting to your code (E.g. is it a JAX-WS type of invocation?  JAX-RS , etc.)?

Comment: @ScottKurz I've updated my question regarding OpenLiberty specs

Comment: jaxws-2.2 uses jaxb-2.2 as a dependency so you might try switching your maven dependency to <version>2.2.12</version>. Not sure if that will have an effect, but its worth keeping them aligned I think.